# Video controls only when video plays (html5)

Tags: javascript, html, video, controls

I'm using the video element to show a video on my website. I used the poster attribute to show an image with some text and a play button on it. With Javascript I defined that if you click on the video element/poster, the video starts.
Now i want the controls of the video (play/pause-button, sound, full-screen) only shown when the video is played, so you can pause the video or adjust the volume. I added the controls attribute but now it also show the controls when the video is not played.

```
<video id="video" class="width-100 display-none borderRadius-l breakPointM-display-inline video" poster="splashvideo.png" preload="auto" controls  width="300" height="150">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Can i fix this with some javascript or css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this was asked quite a while back, but I wanted to see if someone had a nice solution to this which came up empty so thought I share mine.

To answer your question; Yes you can fix this with Javascript or CSS.

The solution I came up with was to use Javascript to add the controls attribute upon clicking on the video. So the same way you have a click event handling the play and pause using JS, you just add or remove the attribute "controls" at the same time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
`el.setAttribute('controls','');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute
`el.removeAttribute('controls');`

**Testing**

- **Chrome (56):** Works, controls fade in and fade out very quickly, show again when mouse is moved on video
- **Firefox (52):** Works, controls don't show until mouse is moved on video
- **Safari (10):** Works, controls remain visible until mouse moves outside of video
- **Edge:** Didn't test :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the full solution looks like this:

HTML:
Video plays when poster is clicked using onclick="this.play".

```
<video id="video1" class="width-100 display-none borderRadius-l breakPointM-display-inline video" 
poster="https://placehold.it/350x150" preload="auto" width="300" height="150" onclick="this.play()">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

JS Code:
Add event listeners for playing and pause, the below removes controls if paused, brings back controls while playing.

```
var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');

function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
    if (e.type == 'playing') {
     //add controls
     video1.setAttribute("controls","controls");
    } else if (e.type == 'pause') {
   //remove controls
   video1.removeAttribute("controls");
    }
}

//Add event listeners
video1.addEventListener('playing', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
video1.addEventListener('pause', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/pypgjt4r/